# How to use non-static @TempDir with custom @ConfigurationProperties during testing

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am working on a Spring Batch application which processes image files, where the path to the images is configurable using `application.yml`:

```
files:
    image-path: /var/images
```

I'm trying to use a **non-static** field annotated with `@TempDir` in one of my Spring Boot integration tests, so that I get a new temporary folder for each test:

```
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = ImageBatchJobApplication.class)
class ImageBatchJobTests {

    @TempDir
    private Path imagePath;

    ...
}
```

The problem is that I somehow need to pass this temporary folder path to my custom `@ConfigurationProperties` class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "files")
public record MyConfiguration(String imagePath) { }
```

I tried to use a `@DynamicPropertySource` where I would add the temporary directory to the registry:

```
@DynamicPropertySource
private static void testProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("files.image-path", imagePath::toString);
}
```

but of course from within a static method I can not access the non-static `imagePath` field. I thought about using a custom `ApplicationCOntextInitializer`, however there I would run into the same problem of how to access the instance variable. Does anybody have an idea how I could pass my `@TempDir` path to the `MyConfiguration` before each test tun?

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom [Test Fixture](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamicpropertysource#an-alternative-test-fixtures)?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work for me. Found a solution using DI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to inject the configuration class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` in the `beforeEach` method and update the value there:

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = ImageBatchJobApplication.class)
class ImageBatchJobApplicationTests {

    @TempDir
    private Path imagePath;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(@Autowired MyConfiguration config) {
        config.setImagePath(imagePath.toString());
    }
}
```